# Best video from Mix 2010?

Tags: video

#### What was the best video/session at Mix 2010?

The [videos](http://live.visitmix.com/videos) have been put up for most of the sessions now, I can't watch all of them - so any favourites? any 'must-see's?

Comment: Why on earth would someone vote to close this as "subjective and argumentative"?? It's even marked community wiki! Geez.

Comment: who knows Josh.  I'm not after 'reputation' just some shout out's as to which videos are worth my time watching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike Swanson has a great wrap up on Mix10 with top 20 sessions ranked by “overall satisfaction”:

http://blogs.msdn.com/mswanson/archive/2010/03/19/mix10-wrap-up.aspx

1. Advanced Web Debugging with Fiddler (Eric Lawrence)
2. The Tale of JavaScript. I Mean ECMAScript. (Douglas Crockford)
3. Reactive Extensions for JavaScript (Erik Meijer)
4. Web Deployment Made Awesome: If You're Using XCopy, You're Doing It Wrong (Scott Hanselman)
5. Search Engine Optimization for Microsoft Silverlight (Brad Abrams)
6. Introducing the Silverlight Rough Cut Editor (Jason Suess)
7. Accessing Data in a Microsoft .NET-Connected Web Application (Shyam Pather)
8. The Laws of User Experience (Anthony Franco)
9. Dynamic Layout and Transitions for Microsoft Silverlight 4 with Microsoft Expression Blend (Kenny Young)
10. Microsoft Silverlight and Windows Azure: A Match Made for the Web (Matt Kerner)
11. Implementing OData: How to Create a Feed for That (Mike Flasko)
12. Modern Web Form Design (Luke Wroblewski)
13. Designing and Delivering Scalable and Resilient Web Services (Ron Jacobs)
14. Improving Software Quality for the Modern Web (Euan Garden)
15. An Hour With Bill Buxton (Bill Buxton)
16. The Elephant in the Room (Nishant Kothary)
17. Do You Speak My Language? Microsoft Translator and the Power of Collaboration (Vikram Dendi and Neil Roodyn)
18. Beyond File | New Company: From Cheesy Sample to Social Platform (Scott Hanselman)
19. OData: There's a Feed for That (Pablo Castro)
20. Microsost Silverlight 4 Business Applications (Scott Morrison)

He's also got links to RSS feeds, downloaders etc. for each of these sessions.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion Rob Eisenberg's "Build Your Own MVVM Framework" which has gotten a lot of praise. It acknowledges what we've all known - the reason there's so many MVVM frameworks is because we all want our own. But it provides a nice, very light, basic foundation and does not rehash the same old MVVM introductions.

Here's a review and link.

http://codebetter.com/blogs/wardbell/archive/2010/03/19/rob-e-s-mini-mvvm-framework-mix10.aspx